# Why does AWK delete leading space?

Tags: awk

Why is the leading space not printed in the following example?

```
$ echo " foo bar" | awk '{ $2 = "baz"; print $0 }'
foo baz
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you "touch" the fields in a record (in this case by assigning to the second field), awk reformats the whole record. So `$1` is "foo" and each field is separated by the Output Field Separator `OFS`, which is a single space by default.

To keep the line intact, you could change your code to something like this:

```
$ echo " foo bar" | awk '{ sub(/bar/, "baz"); print $0 }'
 baz bar
```

Operating on the line as a whole, rather than the individual fields, means that the reformatting doesn't take place.

...Although at that point, you may as well be using sed:

```
$ echo " foo bar" | sed 's/bar/baz/'
 baz bar
```

Comment: OK, so I need to modify `$0` instead to keep the spaces intact.

Comment: I'm writing a separate awk script, so sed is not an option.

Comment: Never do that as it'll fail when `bar` appears as part of a field before the field you're interested in. Try it if the input is `" rhubarb bar"`.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you modify a field of a record awk re-compiles the record, separating fields with the value of OFS and stripping leading and trailing blanks from the record. To keep white-space intact you must modify the whole record, not any one field of it.

For example to do what you want with GNU awk would be:

```
$ echo " foo bar" | awk '{ $0=gensub(/(^\s*\S+\s+).*/,"\\1baz",""); print $0 }'
 foo baz
```

Do NOT think that can just do `sub(/bar/,"baz")` as that will fail when "bar" appears earlier in the record than as the 2nd field:

```
$ echo " rhubarb bar" | awk '{ sub(/bar/, "baz"); print $0 }'
 rhubazb bar

$ echo " rhubarb bar" | awk '{ $0=gensub(/(^\s*\S+\s+).*/,"\\1baz",""); print $0 }'
 rhubarb baz
```

In general, to replace the Nth field of a record where the fields are separated by the default FS would be:

```
$0=gensub(/((^\s*\S+\s+){N-1})\S+/,"\\1baz","")
```

and for FS values that can't be negated in a character class, this time using GNU awk for the 4th arg to split():

```
awk -F'<whatever>' '{split($0,f,FS,s); f[2]="baz"; r=s[0]; for (i=i;i<=NF;i++) r=r f[i] s[i]; $0=r; print $0}'
```

Answer (score 2):

awk splits lines on spaces.

For that line awk sets `$1="foo"` and `$2="bar"`.

When you don't modify anything about a line awk just prints the input line back out.

When you do modify the line (by assigning to one of the fields) awk recombines the fields to form the output line (it uses the value of `OFS` to recombine the fields).

So awk takes your two fields (now `$1="foo"` and `$2="baz"`) and does (effectively) this:

```
printf "%s%s%s\n", $1, OFS, $2
```